# How to block the login page once logged?

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter

i am learning codeigniter 4, i am trying to get the login page block once my user is logged but i am getting the error too many redirection and i dont know how to fix it

my login controller:

```
public function login()
    {
        $validated = $this->validate([
            'email' => 'required|valid_email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ],[
            'email'=> [
                'required' => 'E-mail required',
                'valid_email' => 'E-mail not valid',
            ],
            'password'=> [
                'required'=> 'Password required',
            ]
        ]);

        if (!$validated) {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('errors', $this->validator->getErrors());
        } else {
            $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
            $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
        }

        $usersModel = new UsersModel();

        $dataUser = $usersModel->getByEmail($email);

        if (count($dataUser) > 0) {
            $hashUser = $dataUser['users_password'];
            if (password_verify($password, $hashUser)) {
                unset($hashUser);
                session()->set('isLoggedIn', true);
                session()->set('nome', $dataUser['users_name']);
                return redirect()->to(base_url('app/dashboard'));
            }
        }

    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session()->destroy();
        return redirect()->to(base_url('login'));
    }
```

my auth filter:

```
if ((bool)session()->isLoggedIn != true) {
            return redirect()->to(base_url('login'));
        }
```

and in the configs/filter i am adding in the filter globals

```
'before' => [
            'auth'=> [
                'except' => [
                    'login',
                    '/',
                    'search/*',
                    'post/*',
                    'sobre',
                    'contato'
                ]
            ]
```

the thing is, if i change the auth to check if has the session and remove the exception 'login' i get the error in my login and in my app/dashboard, what iam doing wrong here ?

i already tryit change the auth filter to check if exist the session but always give me the error too many redirections

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the session variables you create here exist. If they do you return an error. there are other ways but this is the siplest.

Comment: already tryit and if i go to the login page they dont redirect me to the dashboard page even having the session

Comment: Do you have your login as a page you heve to be logged in for? Than u redirect to login and back to /. This keeps going forever.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you can modify your authentication filter to exclude the 'login' route only if the user is not logged in. Here's how you can do it:

```
if ((bool)session()->isLoggedIn != true && service('router')->controllerName() !== 'LoginController') {
    return redirect()->to(base_url('login'));
}
```

```
'before' => [
    'auth'=> [
        'except' => [
            '/',
            'search/*',
            'post/*',
            'sobre',
            'contato'
        ]
    ]
]
```

---

If it's not work then try 2nd way
Add redirection in the login form page

```
    // Check if the user is already logged in
    if (session()->isLoggedIn) {
        return redirect()->to(base_url('app/dashboard'));
    }
```

I hope it works for you,

Thanks!

Comment: i am sorry to say but if i do like that the auth keep verifying if the session exist and dont redirect, now i am trying to create another auth filter to only verify the session and block all the others links

Comment: Can you show me the app/Filters/auth.php code, also please confirm are you update the filter in app/Config/Filters.php?
Example - https://pastebin.com/raw/apWRGZXa

Comment: yeah of course https://pastebin.com/gXUp87Pt

Comment: update your configuration to use this new filter separately from your existing authentication filter:  Your code Line 82 || check line number 27 https://pastebin.com/apWRGZXa

Comment: Here - https://snipboard.io/SkP3YO.jpg

Comment: i still dont get what change do you have made and i read more then 10 times

Comment: Line no: 86 https://pastebin.com/PDkfKsjs (https://snipboard.io/K0pMUw.jpg)

Comment: that doenst help me solving my problem, sorry to say that

Answer (score 0):

you can use the sessions to do this job like this :

```html
      if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == 1
                {
                    redirect('dashboard', 'location');
                }
                else{
                    redirect('logout', 'location');
                }
```

also as i believe that you have a function called like this :

```
public function login_page()
```

if so, so you have to add this code to it at the top

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==1) redirect('dashboard', 'location');
```

hope that it will help you.